# TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from uint256[3] memory to uint256[] memory requested

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, implicit-conversion

so I got a problem while developing a contract using a **foundry**. So I have a function that takes uint256 with array type as an argument. But when I did the test, It showed an **implicit error.**

TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from uint256[3] memory to uint256[] memory requested.

```
contract Test {
    uint256[] private threshold = [1000, 2000, 3000];

    function setThreshold(uint256[] memory _threshold) public onlyOwner {       
        threshold = _threshold;
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an error in your script where you call setThreshold function or error is in your tests.

I've made little changes to your code for simpler check

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {
    uint256[] public threshold = [21000, 2000, 3000];

    function setThreshold(uint256[] memory _threshold) public {
        threshold = _threshold;
    }
}
```

Here is my deploy script:
from brownie import Test, accounts

```
def main():
    check = Test.deploy({"from": accounts[0]})
    print(check.threshold(0))
    check.setThreshold([1000, 1000, 1000], {"from": accounts[0]})
    print(check.threshold(0))
```

And here is an output:

> Running 'scripts/deploy.py::main'...
> Transaction sent:    0x63fba19e52cb9064c43d25f76b43151ddc5cbf4ba55ca30f469322eeabd824bf
> Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 0
> Test.constructor confirmed   Block: 1   Gas used: 257509 (2.15%)
> Test deployed at: 0x3194cBDC3dbcd3E11a07892e7bA5c3394048Cc87
> **21000**
> Transaction sent: 0xe48cd3a8231fdc4e246b5e93aa1fc4544dabce6ef4f19bfd65fb8044d42ad9db
> Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 1
> Test.setThreshold confirmed   Block: 2   Gas used: 39640 (0.33%)
> **1000**
> Terminating local RPC client...